# GMaps: set MarkerOptions

Tags: google-maps, markermanager

The Google Maps [MarkerManager][1] has a function to get a marker at a location:

```
getMarker(lat:Number, lng:Number, zoom:Number)
```

with this description:

> Returns a marker given latitude,
>   longitude and zoom. If the marker does
>   not exist, the method will return a
>   new marker. If a new marker is
>   created, it will NOT be added to the
>   manager.

However, the standard GMarker constructor takes a set of MarkerOptions:

```
GMarker(latlng:GLatLng, opts?:GMarkerOptions)
```

Is there a way to set the MarkerOptions on a new marker created by getMarker()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the GMarkerOptions can only be set when a GMarker is constructed.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it would probably be best to simply build your own GMarker whenever the `getMarker()` function returns a new marker.